# Performance: Using indexing and partitioning (PostgreSQL)

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, indexing, partitioning

I have a fairly simple database model. My table "main" looks like this:

```
| id (PK) | device_id (int) | msg_type (int) | rawdata (text) | timestamp (date+time) |
```

Therefore each received message is stored within this table, including the message type, timestamp, the device which sent it and the rawdata.

In addition for each possible msg_type (in total approx. 30) I have a separate table storing the parsed raw data. Example for the table "main_type1":

```
| id (PK) | main_id (FK) | device_id (int) | attribute_1 | attribute_2 | attribute_n |
```

(Structure differs for each msg_type and the messages are not equally distributed meaning some tables are hugh some tables are small).

Please note that the device_id is always included within the rawdata, so each table has this column.

**Now to my problem:**

I used to have queries such as:

```
select attribute_1, attribute_2 from main_type1 inner join main on main_type1.main_id = main.id where timestamp > X and timestamp < Y and main.device_id = Z
```

At the beginning everything was sufficient and also fast. But now my database has more than 400.000.000 entries in "main". Queries are taking up to 15 minutes now.

**Indexing**

I tried to use indexing such as:

```
CREATE INDEX device_id_index ON main (device_id);
```

Well, now I can retreive data much faster from the main table, but it does not help with joins. My biggest problem here is that I  stored the timestamp information only in the main table. So I have to join all the time... is this a general failure of my database model? I tried to avoid storing timestamps twice.

**Partitioning**

Would one solution be to create a new table with rawdata for each device_id by using partitioning? I would then (of course automatically) create appropriate partitions such as:

```
main_device_id_343223
main_device_id_4563
main_device_id_92338
main_device_id_4142315
```

Would this give me speed advantages related to the joins? What other options do I have? For the sake of completeness: I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: Partitioning is not a query performance feature, it usually makes query perf worse compared to using a good indexing strategy.

Comment: Why are you indexing on device when your query does not mention device at all?

Comment: @usr: You are right, I added the missing id to the query. Of course I am trying to get data for a specific device. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Have you tried creating the ideal indexes for this particular query yet? One on each table. Report the perf numbers for that configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by "prefect indexes"? Instructions are a bit unclear, could you give me more information about which indexes I should use? I would then report performance rates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your problem is the time of execution of a `join`, the first thing to do is try to speed up the query by creating indexes in the following way:

1. Indexes that help the join itself, in this case an index on the foreign key `main.id` in `main_type1` (note that a foreign key declaration does not automatically create an index):

   ```
   CREATE INDEX main_type_main_id_index ON main_type1(main_id);
   ```
2. Indexes that help in restricting the set of data considered by the query, in this case on the timestamp attribute:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX main_timestamp_index ON main(timestamp);
   ```

You can also consider the possibility of creating a [Partial Index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/indexes-partial.html) for the attribute timestamp, if your queries only look for specific subset of the values.

If these indexes do not speed up the query in a significant way, then you should follow the answer of [@klin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31091717/2246380).

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer. If its an answer expand it or add more details else delete it and add it as a comment to the question.

Comment: Thank for the comment @Ram, I expanded the query since I think it could be a solution for the question.

Comment: Thanks for expanding the answer. I edited it to improve it.

Comment: Thanks to Renzo and klin. Indexing helped improving the performance, queries now take approx. 1/10 of the original time. However, this is still too long. For that reason I will also try using partitioning in the near future

Comment: Ok, but I'll give also a possibility to partial indexes in the case in which the timestamp that you are using more frequently are a (relatively) small subset of all the timestamps (for instance if you are making frequent queries starting from a certain time_.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the scenario: first, create indexes proposed by Renzo. If that does not improve performance enough, try using partitions.

[From the documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-partitioning.html)

> Partitioning can provide several benefits: Query performance can be
>   improved dramatically in certain situations, particularly when most of
>   the heavily accessed rows of the table are in a single partition or a
>   small number of partitions. The partitioning substitutes for leading
>   columns of indexes, reducing index size and making it more likely that
>   the heavily-used parts of the indexes fit in memory. (...)

If you use partitioning all queries containing references to a specific device (such as in your question) will be much faster. 
Only those queries that will apply to many device_id (e.g. containg aggregates) may be slower.